# Window fade out in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have a ViewModel, from which I show a Window that should fade out. It fades only first time, and then It stops.

```
public class MessageBoxViewModel
{
     private MessageBoxView _message;
     private MessageBoxResult _result = MessageBoxResult.No;

     public MessageBoxViewModel()
     {
        //...creating commands...
     }

     private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
     {
          //Close window with fade out animation
          _message.Closing -= Window_Closing;
          e.Cancel = true;
          var animation = new DoubleAnimation
          {
              To=0,
              Duration=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
              FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop
           };
 
           animation.Completed += (s, a) => { _message.Close(); };
           _message.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, animation);
       }
      
       public MessageBoxResult Show(string Text, string Title)
       {
           //...setting properties which View is bound to

           _message = new MessageBoxView
           {
              DataContext = this
           };
           _message.Closing += Window_Closing;
           _message.ShowDialog();
  
          return _result;
       }
 }
```

And this is how I call messagebox in different ViewModel:

```
 class SomeViewMNodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
      private MessageBoxViewModel _message = new MessageBoxViewModel(); 
      public SomeViewModel()
      {
         //....
      }

      private void ShowMessages(object parameter) //Command on click of some button
      {
           _message.Show("Hey I'm fading.", "Fade out"); //Fading is succesfully done

          _message.Show("Hey I'm fading second time.", "Fade out"); //Fading doesn't work anymore
       }

  }
```

I have tried to stop an animation as suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-set-a-property-after-animating-it-with-a-storyboard?redirectedfrom=MSDN), but that doesn't seem to work. Neither does Opacity property actually change - a simple check with `var j = _message.GetAnimationBaseValue(UIElement.OpacityProperty)` ==> allways shows value of 1, in animation.Completed or after inicializing new Window.

I've figured that animation works If I don't use **_message** variable, but instead declare a new instance of **ViewModel**, e.g. `var win = new MessageBoxViewModel()`. But I'm using this custom MessageBox for all errors & notifications in many ViewModels, so I would like to use only **_message** variable If possible (I would make it global).

Without MVVM and re-initiliazing instance of Window I can make animation working everytime, **but how can I animate Window in MVVM properly?**

Comment: Does it work if you dispose of _message and re-instantiate it the second time?

Comment: @JeremyHodge no, one of first things I tried :)

Comment: Are you creating a window in a view model...? This goes against all what MVVM is about.

Comment: @mm8, yes, I'm doing that. I've looked examples of dialog service for custom messageboxes, but they do same. Only difference is that they use interfaces and inject viewmodels with Caliburn micro etc. So my ViewModel could be called DialogServiceViewModel as well. Unless I'm wrong about concept of interface.

Comment: @Lucy82: The "only" difference is that you then can mock youw dialog service. That's the point of using it...

Comment: @mm8, what do you suggest then - where should I call  or create Window If not from ViewModel ?

Comment: @Lucy82: In a service that you inject the view model with of course.

Comment: does it call the Window_Closing the second time?

Comment: @mm8, not quite following you anymore. You mean that there is no workaround other than using Unity, Caliburn micro etc. ? ...Yes It does call Window_closing next time, it goes through every lines of code as on first attempt.

Comment: @Lucy82: I am just saying that your code is not MVVM. You may remove the view model from the question and simply ask how to animate a window.

Comment: @mm8, and how can I make It MVVM ? only using frameworks (Caliburn,,,) or is there another approach?...Sorry for harrasing you, this just doesn't comply to my logic.

Comment: Please rephrase your actual question a bit. Is it about how to animate the window or MVVM?

Comment: @mm8 I re-phrased question and title. I want to have Window animation working everytime, in MVVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the point in making the `Window` instance global and reuse the `Window` instance. You should generally avoid creating global (`static`) instances.
Creating a small `Window` instance from time to time is quite affordable. Instantiation costs are unnoticeable in this case.

Anyway, if you want to reuse a `Window` instance, you are not allowed to close it. Closing a `Window` disposes its unmanaged resources.

If you want to use `Window.Close()`, you have to override the virtual `Window.OnClosing` method (or listen to the `Window.Closing` event) and cancel closing and instead set the window's visibility to `Visibilty.Collapsed`:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
  //Close window with fade out animation
  _message.Closing -= Window_Closing;
  e.Cancel = true;
  var animation = new DoubleAnimation
  {
    To=0,
    Duration=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop
  };

  animation.Completed += (s, a) => _message.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; ;

  _message.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, animation);
}
```

But as some have noticed already, this implementation is violating the MVVM pattern. You are not allowed to introduce a coupling between the view and the view model. The goal of MVVM is to remove this exact coupling.
The view model is not allowed to handle any UI components.

The following example shows how implement a dialog infrastructure that complies with the MVVM pattern.

The example consists of four simple steps

1. Create a `DialogViewModel`
2. Create the `Dialog`, which will extend `Window`. It will use a `DataTemplate` to show its content based on the `DialogViewModel` (or subtypes) in the `Dialog.DataContext`
3. Create a public property e.g., `DialogViewModel` in your view model that needs to show the dialog.
4. Let the parent control e.g. `MainWindow` actually show the `Dialog`.

### Example implementation

1. Implement a view model that serves as the data source for the actual dialog window:

   **DialogViewModel.cs**
   This view model defines an `AcceptCommand` and a `CancelCommand` which can be bound to corresponding dialog buttons.
   When one of the commands is executed a `CloseRequested` event is raised.
   The constructor takes a delegate which serves as a callback that is invoked when the dialog was closed.

   ```
    public class DialogViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
      public DialogViewModel(string dialogCaption, string message, Action<DialogViewModel> dialogClosedHandler)
      {
        this.DialogCaption = dialogCaption;
        this.Message = message;
        this.DialogClosedHandler = dialogClosedHandler;
      }

      public void HandleResult() => this.DialogClosedHandler.Invoke(this);

      private string dialogCaption;
      public string DialogCaption
      {
        get => this.dialogCaption;
        set
        {
          this.dialogCaption = value;
          OnPropertyChanged();
        }
      }

      private string message;
      public string Message
      {
        get => this.message;
        set
        {
          this.message = value;
          OnPropertyChanged();
        }
      }

      public ICommand AcceptCommand => new RelayCommand(param => this.IsAccepted = true);
      public ICommand CancelCommand => new RelayCommand(param => this.IsAccepted = false);

      private bool isAccepted;
      public bool IsAccepted
      {
        get => this.isAccepted;
        set
        {
          this.isAccepted = value;
          OnPropertyChanged();
          OnCloseRequested();
        }
      }

      public event EventHandler<DialogEventArgs> CloseRequested;
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      private Action<DialogViewModel> DialogClosedHandler { get; }

      protected virtual void OnCloseRequested()
      {
        this.CloseRequested?.Invoke(this, new DialogEventArgs(this));
      }

      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
    }
   ```
2. Implement the dialog window, which will show its content based on the `DialogViewModel` using a `DataTemplate`. To create different types of specialized dialogs, simply ceate a specialized dialog view model and a corresponding `DataTemplate`.

   Every eventual dialog animation is also implemented in this class using XAML and `EventTrigger`, which triggers on a `DialogClosed` routed event.

   The `Dialog` will listen to the `DialogViewModel.CloseRequested` event to close itself. Since you wished to reuse the `Dialog` instance, the `Dialog` intercepts the invocation of `Close()` to collapse itself. This behavior can be enabled using the constructor.

   After closing itself, the `Dialog` sets the `DialogEventArgs.Handled` property to `true`, which will trigger the invocation of the dialog closed callback (which was registered with the `DialogViewModel`), so that the calling view model, that showed the dialog, can continue to execute:

   **Dialog.xaml.cs**

   ```
    public partial class Dialog : Window
    {
      #region DialogClosedRoutedEvent

      public static readonly RoutedEvent DialogClosedRoutedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "DialogClosed",
        RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
        typeof(Dialog));

      public event RoutedEventHandler DialogClosed
      {
        add => AddHandler(Dialog.DialogClosedRoutedEvent, value);
        remove => RemoveHandler(Dialog.DialogClosedRoutedEvent, value);
      }

      #endregion

      private bool IsReuseEnabled { get; }

      public Dialog(bool isReuseEnabled = false)
      {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.IsReuseEnabled = isReuseEnabled;
        this.DataContextChanged += OnDialogViewModelChanged;
      }

      public Dialog(DialogViewModel dialogViewModel) : this()
      {
        this.DataContext = dialogViewModel;
      }

      private void OnDialogViewModelChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
        HandleDialogNewViewModel(e.OldValue as DialogViewModel, e.NewValue as DialogViewModel);
      }

      private void HandleDialogNewViewModel(DialogViewModel oldDialogViewModel, DialogViewModel newDialogViewModel)
      {
        if (oldDialogViewModel != null)
        {
          oldDialogViewModel.CloseRequested -= CloseDialog;
        }

        if (newDialogViewModel != null)
        {
          newDialogViewModel.CloseRequested += CloseDialog;
        }
      }

      private void CloseDialog(object sender, DialogEventArgs e)
      {
        Close();
        e.Handled = true;
      }

      #region Overrides of Window

      protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
      {
        if (!this.IsReuseEnabled)
        {
          return;
        } 

        e.Cancel = true;
        Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
          () => RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Dialog.DialogClosedRoutedEvent, this)),
          DispatcherPriority.Background);
        base.OnClosing(e);
      }

      #endregion

      private void DialogClosedAnimation_OnCompleted(object? sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
      }
    }
   ```

   **Dialog.xaml**
   To customize the layout, edit the `DataTemplate`:

   ```
    <Window x:Class="Dialog"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Height="450"
            Width="800" 
            Title="{Binding DialogCaption}">
      <Window.Resources>

        <!-- 
          To create more specialized dialogs, 
          create a dedicated DataTemplate for each dialog view model type.
        -->

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DialogViewModel}">
          <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Button Content="Ok" Command="{Binding AcceptCommand}" />
              <Button Content="Cancel" IsDefault="True" IsCancel="True" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" />
            </StackPanel>
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </Window.Resources>

      <!-- Animations triggered by the DialogClosed event -->
      <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:Dialog.DialogClosed">
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard Completed="DialogClosedAnimation_OnCompleted">
              <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"  To="0" Duration="0:0:1" FillBehavior="Stop"/>
              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" FillBehavior="Stop">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
      </Window.Triggers>

      <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
      </Grid>
    </Window>
   ```
3. To trigger the displaying of the `Dialog` let the view model create the `DialogViewModel` and assign it to a `public` property.

   **ViewModel.cs**

   ```
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
      public void SaveToFile(object data, string filePath)
      {
        // Check if file exists (pseudo)
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath))
        {
          // Show the dialog
          this.DialogViewModel = new DialogViewModel("File Exists Dialog", "File exists. Replace file?", OnDialogResultAvailable);
        }
        else
        {
          Save(data, filePath);
        }
      }

      public void Save(object data, string filePath)
      {
        // Write data to file
      }

      private void OnDialogResultAvailable(DialogViewModel dialogViewModel)
      {
        if (dialogViewModel.IsAccepted)
        { 
          // User has accepted to overwrite file             
          Save(data, filePath);
        }
      }

      private DialogViewModel dialogViewModel;
      public DialogViewModel DialogViewModel
      {
        get => this.dialogViewModel;
        set
        {
          this.dialogViewModel = value;
          OnPropertyChanged();
        }
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
    }
   ```
4. To actually show the dialog, let the parent `Window` (e.g., `MainWindow`) listen to the property changes of `ViewModel.DialogViewModel` e.g., by setting up a `Binding`:

   **MainWindow.xaml.cs**

   ```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
     public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentDialogViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
       "CurrentDialogViewModel",
       typeof(DialogViewModel),
       typeof(MainWindow),
       new PropertyMetadata(default(DialogViewModel), MainWindow.OnDialogViewModelChanged));

     public DialogViewModel CurrentDialogViewModel
     {
       get => (DialogViewModel) GetValue(MainWindow.CurrentDialogViewModelProperty);
       set => SetValue(MainWindow.CurrentDialogViewModelProperty, value);
     }

     private static void OnDialogViewModelChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
     {
       if (e.NewValue == null)
       {
         return;
       }

       (d as MainWindow).ShowDialog(e.NewValue as DialogViewModel);
     }

     private void ShowDialog(DialogViewModel dialogViewModel)
     {
       this.Dialog.DataContext = dialogViewModel;
       this.Dialog.ShowDialog();

       // Alternative recommended approach:
       // var dialog = new Dialog(dialogViewModel);
       // dialog.ShowDialog();
     }

     private Dialog Dialog { get; set; }

     public MainWindow()
     {
       InitializeComponent();

       // Create a reusable dial instance (not recommended)
       this.Dialog = new Dialog(true);
     }

     private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
       (this.DataContext as ViewModel).SaveToFile(null, string.Empty);
     }
   }
   ```

   **MainWindow.xaml**

   ```
   <Window x:Class="MainWindow"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:"
           mc:Ignorable="d"
           Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
     <Window.DataContext>
       <local:ViewModel />
     </Window.DataContext>
     <Window.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="local:MainWindow">

         <-- Observe view model DialogViewModel property using data binding -->
         <Setter Property="CurrentDialogViewModel" Value="{Binding DialogViewModel}" />
       </Style>
     </Window.Resources>

     <Button Content="Show Dialog" Click="Button_Click" />
   </Window>
   ```

### Remarks

You can improve reusability by moving the code implemented in `MainWindow` to an attached behavior.

Comment: what an in-depth answer. Many thanks for this, now I get the picture. Though I didn't imagine that I would need to do all this for displaying dialogs in MVVM. My real problem will need more coding, but I think you explained biggest concerns clearly, so I'm back in a "motivation mode". Thanks again :)

Comment: I think it looks  more complicated than it actually is. And this solution is reusable. WPF doesn't provide a way to show dialogs from the view model. I generally believe that showing dialogs from the view model is the result of bad design. There is absolutely no need to do this. Showing dialogs should be only the requirement of a view component. Especially when asking for user input. Handling user input is the responsibility of the UI - user interface. So while it is possible to show dialogs from the view model without violating MVVM, the need to do so is already a violation.

Comment: Take the example code that shows a dialog when the view model fails to create a new file, due to the presence of a file with the same name. One could argue that this is a classic case for throwing an e.g. `FileExists` exception which the view can handle by showing a dialog or using data validation. You can implement data validation either in the view model or in the view. You could validate the selected file path e.g. using a `ValidationRule` and show a dialog in response of a failed validation. Simple like that.

Comment: The view model doesn't have to worry about messages for user interaction or dialog titles or dialog types. That's avoidable and leads to better code.

Comment: only thing that concerns me using you suggestion is all that code behind. Is that direct violation of MVVM or just not desirable? After all, It's only view specific code?

Comment: MVVM is not about code-behind. In fact the definition of a design pattern is that it must be language or compiler independent. The pattern's goal is to achieve better testability and extensibility by decoupling the view from the business logic. It achieves this by introducing the layers or components view, view model and model. It's an evolution of MVP. The MVVM pattern is not about data binding, ICommand or code-behind or even C#. You can implement this pattern in every language that supports mechanisms to realize the coupling between the components.

Comment: For example C# offers data binding and ICommand to achieve this. Code-behind or more precisely `partial class` is a special language or compiler feature of C#. The rule to keep the code-behind file empty is because WinForms developers start to use WPF. WinForms doesn't know XAML and so the complete UI logic and layout was written in C#. So to fight the natural instinct to continue this, insteda of learning XAML, tutorials came up with this mantra. And it's true that writing UI is very much easier using XAML than it is using C#.

Comment: But there are moments that you must write C# e.g. to derive from a class in order to extend it or handling CLR events (where there is no routed event) or defining properties e.g. `DependencyProperty` etc. or executing methods or overriding virtual members and more. The example uses almost no code-behind. What is possible in XAML is done in XAML. I used XAML to animate the window other than you did - not because it violates MVVM but because it's so much easier to write.

Comment: XAML is the primary choice when writing UI, therefore every UI related feature like animations or templates are designed to be used with XAML. It's funny how you are concerned about writing code into the code-behind file, but have absolutely no issue with writing and handling animations in your view model or showing windows from your view model.

Comment: I'm still learning WPF a lot, I come from years of Winforms, so everything is pretty much new to me. I also don't have to do a MVVM myself, I'm a standalone programmer in my company, so there is no need for unit testing. But as always I want to raise my knowledge, and beside that I like code to be more maintanable. Anyway, thanks for all your deep insight answers.